# Does an improvised weapon similar to a weapon with special features benefit from those features as well?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, improvised-weaponry

Another question about improvised weaponry. I know how the size category and damage of an improvised weapon is determined, I also know that improvised weapons always crit on a natural 20 for double damage, but what about special properties ?

Examples :

- using pieces of scrap metal as shurikens : are they also considered ammunition for the purpose of drawing them and what happens to them when they are thrown ?
- using a kitchen knife as a dagger : does it give a +2 bonus on Sleight of Hands checks to conceal it ?
- using a pointy metal rod as a rapier : does it give the option to replace Strenght with Dexterity for Attack rolls and also suffer the disadvantage of not increasing the bonus damage from Strenght when used two-handed ?

For short : if an improvised weapon is close to a weapon with special properties or drawbacks, does the improvised weapon get them too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to [the D20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Improvised-Weapons):

> To determine the **size category** and **appropriate damage** for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match.

This means the only aspects of an improvised weapon which are determined by similarity to an actual weapon are size category and damage. Any special features only apply to a proper weapon.

Answer (score 2):

As Philipp said, but consider the following:

impr-shurikens - well, it doesn't have special abilities, so you'd throw it as you would a melee weapon. Makes sense as it isn't built to be aerodynamic. By RAW, then, it also wouldn't break, if I remember correctly. This is amusing in that you can throw toothpicks all day long and not have them break, but throw a shuriken...

A Kitchen Knife is basically already a weapon - just not one defined explicitly in the book. It has to be sharp enough to cleanly cut meat and fruits and such in order to do its job. I'd just consider it a dagger anyway, but slashing damage.

The metal rod - it's not well-made and balanced to give that ability.